# Python object attributes as variables

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to assign a python object attribute a variable. Here is what I have been trying to do:

```
from read import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data=table('data.txt')

semi=data['data']['a']
ecc = data['data']['e']
incl= data['data']['i']
bias = data['data']['bias']    

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.06, 0.1, 0.4, 0.35])
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.06, 0.6, 0.4, 0.35])
ax3 = fig.add_axes([0.55, 0.6, 0.4, 0.35])
ax4 = fig.add_axes([0.55, 0.1, 0.4, 0.35])

aaa = getattr(ax1,'xaxis')


nax={'ax1':ax1,'ax2':ax2,'ax3':ax3,'ax4':ax4}

for a in sorted(nax):

  aax = {'xaxis':nax[a].get_xaxis()}
  for axis in ['bottom','left']:
     nax[a].spines[axis].set_linewidth(0.5)
  for axis in ['right','top']:
     nax[a].spines[axis].set_visible(False)
  for b in sorted(aax):
     nax[a].b.set_tick_position('bottom')
```

When I run my code it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test1.py", line 35, in <module>
    ax1.b.set_ticks_position('bottom')
AttributeError: 'Axes' object has no attribute 'b'
```

Originally it works when:

```
ax1.xaxis.set_tick_position('bottom')
```

but I need to make the XAxis attribute a variable for the sake of creating plotting templates. 
Any idea how to make the above thing work?

Comment: `getattr` _gets_ an attribute. If you want to _set_ an attribute, you need `setattr`. But there’s rarely a need for either—you can just do `ax1.x = ax1.axis` instead of `setatrr(ax1, 'x', getattr(ax1, 'axis'))`.

Comment: @abarnert Thank you so much! But `ax1.x=ax1.xaxis` will be in a for loop because I have many axes e.g., `ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4,....` so I want to loop the `xaxis` attribute over all axes e.g.,
`nax={'ax1':ax1,'ax2':ax2,'ax3':ax3,'ax4':ax4}
for a in sorted(nax):
  nax[a].x.set_ticks_position('bottom')`

Answer (score 2):

Try `x.set_tick_position('bottom')` instead of `ax1.x.set_tick_position('bottom')`. `x` is already an attribute off of the `ax1` object, so you don't need to access `ax1` again.

Furthermore, no need for `getattr` if you know the name of the attribute statically. You can just do `x = ax1.xaxis`.

Comment: Thank you so much! That works, but my axes are variables as well. Actually, here is a larger portion of what I've been trying to accomplish:
`fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.06, 0.1, 0.4, 0.35])
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.06, 0.6, 0.4, 0.35])
ax3 = fig.add_axes([0.55, 0.6, 0.4, 0.35])
ax4 = fig.add_axes([0.55, 0.1, 0.4, 0.35])

x = getattr(ax1,'xaxis')
nax={'ax1':ax1,'ax2':ax2,'ax3':ax3,'ax4':ax4}

for a in sorted(nax):
  for axis in ['bottom','left']:
     nax[a].x.set_ticks_position('bottom')`

Comment: Sweet. I see you've accepted the answer. Mind upvoting if you found this useful?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to work on the objects directly.

```
nax=[ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4]

for ax in nax:

   for axis in ['bottom','left']:
       ax.spines[axis].set_linewidth(0.5)
   for axis in ['right','top']:
       ax.spines[axis].set_visible(False)

   ax.xaxis.set_tick_position('bottom')
```